# Encrypt a string using a salt in AS3/C#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, c#-4.0, encryption, md5

I'm looking for an example of encrypting a string in Flex/AS3 and reading it back in C#. They C# part isn't as important as the AS3 since I know very little about AS3.

Ideally I would like to make it as short as possible - 16 characters total would be nice.

I tried using EncryptionKeyGenerator from as3corelib but I get an error that it cannot find EncryptedLocalStore.

I think because I need to import com.adobe.air.crypto.EncryptionKeyGenerator and air and flex are conflicting

Comment: You should get into the zip business if you manage to compress an arbitrary string to 16 characters and then read it back to what it was...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) to encrypt on the AS3 side, and use [AesCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx) on the C# side to decrypt. "Salts" would be irrelevant but you can use it as the initialization vector.

Depending on the strength of encryption and the length of the input you're encrypting, you can achieve 16 byte lengths, but be careful with character encoding when passing them as strings. It's typically best to pass a hex byte array.

Comment: I'll try it out. The reason I had said a 16 character string is because it needs to be humanly readable from a AS3 program and manually entered into a C# program for validation. It of course doesn't need to be 16 characters long I just don't want a crazy long string. The input that will be encrypted isn't very long - maybe 32 characters at the longest.

Comment: If just encoding the encrypted bytes, the string won't be human readable, but you could try Base64 encoding it.

Comment: I have another possible idea. Is there a way to create some type of checksum. Let me explain a little more what I'm trying to do. Our users will be prompted with a code and will need to call in the code. We want to the code to verify their user name and a numeric value. In this case I would like to use the code to verify their name and that numeric value. Sort of like a checksum but it can't be something people can duplicate which is why I was thinking of some type of encryption.

Comment: So essentially, multi-factor authentication? If so, I would probably suggest a different approach. In the case of encryption your keys would need to be compiled into the FLA and would then be subject to reproduction. I would suggest having your FLA call a web service that generates a random code, stores it in cache, expires it after X minutes, then give your C# access to the same cache for verification. I can expand on this more, but probably best to start a chat.

Comment: Don't think I can directly import this to chat, but here's a link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19126/discussion-between-lukiffer-and-joe-bonavita

Comment: Sorry - it won't let me start a chat. Seems a min 20 rep is required. Can you clarify further? Counter my last suggestion?

Comment: So I think the easiest thing is for my AS to call a web service and get a 12 digit number. Using this number I would like to encrypt another number with a max length of 12. This number would be displayed to the user who would then give us the number and we would use a C# program to validate it. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem you'll run into is that regardless of what you do to generate the customer-facing number, the FLA will be able to be decompiled and that obfuscation, or encryption even, will be reproducible.